# how to use a model in angular getting the data from an API

Tags: angular, api, model

how to use this model Game

```
export class Game{
  id: any;
  constructor(
    public name: string,
    public image: string,
    public releaseOn: Array<ReleaseOn>,// do it an array of releaseOn platform
    public releaseDate: string,
    public genre: Array<Genres>,// do it an array of genres
    public rating: number,
  ){}
}

export class Genres {
  genre: string
}

export class ReleaseOn {
  releaseOn: string
}
```

into a game.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute  } from '@angular/router';
import { Game } from '../../models/game';
//Services
import { GamesService } from '../../services/games.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-games',
  templateUrl: './games.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./games.component.css']
})
export class GamesComponent implements OnInit {
  public gameslist: any[] = [];
  public game: Game; 


  constructor(
    private gamesService:GamesService,
    private router: Router,
  ) {
    this.game = new Game('', '', [],  '', [], 1 );
    console.log(this.game);
    this.gamesService.getListGames(this.page).subscribe( (data: any) =>{
      console.log(data.results);
      console.log(data);
      this.gameslist = data.results;
      this.count = data.results.length;
      console.log(this.count);
      this.nextpage = data.next;
      console.log(this.nextpage);
     
     });

  }
```

I am loading the object Game into `this.game = new Game('', '', [],  '', [], 1 );`

How to use the model into the component getting the data in a service with the url of the API.
I know how to use a model without arrays but in this case I need to use arrays in model properties.

Comment: instead of data:any give data:Game

Comment: if I put data:Game all data is undefined